# React-native 0.60 - Android build release failed - OutOfMemory

Tags: react-native

After upgrading to RN 0.60 - try to run the command:

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Failed with error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>       2 exceptions were raised by workers:
>       java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Execution of 
>       compression failed.
>        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

The solution for me was:

1. Adding dexoptions in app build.gradle

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    } 
}
```

2. Increasing JVM heap size in gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful - happened to me on 0.61.1

Comment: I was already having this line in my `gradle.properties` : 
`#org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
I uncommented that, added `dexOptions` as above and it worked!

Answer (score 9):

This solution worked for me.

1. Adding following in android/app/build.gradle:

> ```
> android {
>     ...
>     dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "2g" }
>     ...
>     }
> ```

2. Adding following in android/gradle.properties:

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M

Comment: Would I want to adjust this based on my computer's RAM? Mine only has 8GB.

Answer (score 3):

The way I solved this issue was

1. In your ~android/app/build.gradle file add the following line

```
 android {
     ...
     dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
     }
     ...
     }
```

2. In your ~android/gradle.properties add the following line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:largeHeap="true"` to the application portion of the `manifest`.

Don't forget to `recycle()` once you've used Bitmap.

Comment: the problem is during the build and not on runtime